# Why will type="number" attribute break parsing in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, vue.js, input, attributes

I have an inputfield that should only have a set of characters, which I'm doing by parsing the input value through regex. This works in firefox as long as I dont add the attribute type="number".

Is the script wrong or could it be a bug in vue or firefox?

Code here at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9s38rue/14/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: ""
  },
  methods: {
    mask(input) {
      const validCharsForNumberFields = /[0-9]*(,|\.)?[0-9]*/gm
      this.message = input.target.value.match(validCharsForNumberFields)[0]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <!-- Remove the type="number" attribute to make the parsing work in firefox -->
    <input @input="mask" v-model="message" type="number" placeholder="Try numbers">
    <p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*edit: Btw the snippet in this post behave different than the code on jsFiddle. Not sure why. I will try to figure that out. In the mean time, it is the jsFiddle version that behave the same way as running this code locally.*

Comment: I made you a snippet and changed to number. I see indeed, I can add letters in firefox and the parsing gives blank

Comment: Seems like Firefox has some implementations that allow users to type alphanumeric characters inside an input number type. Judging by the way it works, it only allows user to type the characters but do not accept them as they are not numbers.

Comment: Any character can be typed into the input field in Firefox due to the implementation choice within Firefox. Firefox allows the entry of the non-number characters but notes it as invalid within the form.

Comment: Thats why I am using this script to take controll of the inputfield. Which should remove the input after the user typed the key, and then return the parsed value back. But somehow, this doesn't work when the type="number" is present